# How do I integrate GPG with alpine?

Tags: email, gnupg, pgp, alpine-mail

I have tried a couple of howtos, but they seem to either be too out of date or just plain don't work (don't work for me, at least).

How do I sign and encrypt messages, as well as check integrity of received messages (and decrypt them if needed) in pine/alpine?

I tried pipeing (with "|") but the terminal doesn't seem to cooperate so that I can provide my passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used alpine, but since it is based on Pine; I would hazard a guess that this might be helpful:
https://web.archive.org/web/20131221175352/http://www.hackorama.com/network/pgphowto.shtml

Comment: This link has gone dark

Comment: Wayback machine to the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20131221175352/http://www.hackorama.com/network/pgphowto.shtml